# Python XML - appending multiple elements to multiple parents elegantly

Tags: python, lxml

Is there some kind of more elegant way to append elements to their parents where those parents need to be appended to their parents and so on?

For example:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('root')
a = etree.Element('a') 
b = etree.Element('b')
c = etree.Element('c')

# Append one by one

b.append(c)
a.append(b)
root.append(a)
```

Maybe it is possible to append all of this at once? Or do I need to manually append it like in an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your elements and "append" them in a single go if you'd use `SubElement`:

```
root = etree.Element('root')

a = etree.SubElement(root, 'a')
b = etree.SubElement(a, 'b')
c = etree.SubElement(b, 'c')
```

Comment: I think this is better,  because it requires less code :)